# Filezilla download works fine, but command line FTP changes file?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Sorry if this is a repeat question.  I've looked at other threads, but while there are other questions that are similar, none appear to truly address this question:

I have the two files that are needed on an ftp server.  If I use filezilla to drag and drop them into a folder, I can run the files as expected.  If I get the files through command line ftp ("out of the box" ftp in Windows 7), the icon looks different.  Instead of the nice pretty red "Adobe Air" icon it has when I drag and drop it, it has a generic windows type icon with a little shield and a little padlock in the bottom corners of the icon.  I checked the file permissions, but those appear to be the same.  One thing that is definitely different is that when I drag and drop the file w/ Filezilla, it appears to still have a digital signature from adobe (it is the adobe air installer exe file).  When I use the command line ftp, it looks like it loses the digital sig for some reason.  I'm not sure if that is truly the problem though.  Oh, and the command line ftp'd version does not run even if I use run it as admin.

The actual ftp command I'm using is:

ftp -s:myfile.txt ftp.myftpsite.com

where myfile.txt contains the following:

anonymous@myftpsite.com
get AdobeAIRInstaller.exe C:\AdobeAIRInstaller.exe
quit

Oh, and the reason this is a problem is because when I drag and drop the SweepsCoachClient.air file, it runs and installs fine.  When I use command line ftp, it fails to run and install.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "binary" command to your script - it looks like the file is transferred in text mode.